# Refactor javascript function

Tags: javascript, submenu

:) i have created some javascript, it works well, my javascript knowledge limit me to create some compact and light script.
this is some sub menu javascript of aspx framework, here it it the script :

```
if (name === 'diensten/consultancy')
            {
                activeOne();
            }
    else if (name === 'diensten/maatwerk')
            {
                activeTwo();
                diesntenActive();
            }
    else if (name === 'diensten/outsourcing')
            {
                activeThree();
                diesntenActive();
            }
    else if (name === 'diensten/opleidingen')
            {
                activeFour();   
                diesntenActive();
            }
    else if (name === 'diensten/implementaties')
            {
                activeFive();
                diesntenActive();
            }
    else if (name === 'support')
            {
                activeOne();
                supportActive();
            }
    else if (name === 'support/contact')
            {
                activeTwo();
                supportActive();
            }
    else if (name === 'support/download')
            {
                activeThree();
                supportActive();
            }
    else if (name === 'overOns')
            {
                activeOne();
                overOnsActive()
            }
    else if (name === 'overOns/cebes')
            {
                activeTwo();
                overOnsActive()
            }
    else if (name === 'overOns/partner')
            {
                activeThree();
                overOnsActive();
            }
    else if (name === 'overOns/vacatures')
            {
                activeFour();
                overOnsActive();
            }
    else if (name === 'fireman')
            {
                productenActive();
            }
    else if (name === 'prio')
            {
                productenActive();
            }
    else if (name === 'firstwatch')
            {
                productenActive();
            }
    else if (name === 'firstwatchOnline')
            {
                productenActive();
            }
    else if (name === 'cebesFrame')
            {
                productenActive();
            }
    else if (name === 'cms')
            {
                productenActive();
            }   
    return false
```

I am sure there is a way to shorten this javascript, not too urgent, just for give me more knowledge about javascript. Any suggestion are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: maybe the clarification can come not from this script itself but from a larger scope. What is the purpose of the method ?. What are "activeX()" methods ? etc. Kind of changes could be instead of having one method for setting up the UI, all parts could subscribe to an event and decide themselves what to do. Please describe what your are doing

Comment: question has nothing do w/asp.net or aspx, i would look at seeing if you can pass the name into the various Active functions

Answer (score 2):

A start would be to use a `switch` statement instead of a long `if`/`else` tree.

```
switch (name) {
  case 'diensten/consultancy': 
    activeOne (); 
    break;

  case 'diensten/maatwerk':
    activeTwo (); 
    diesntenActive (); 
    break;

  ...

  case 'cms':
    productActive (); 
    break;

  default:
    console.log ("No handler found for '" + name + "'!");
}
```

An alternative method is to use an `object`in which you define functions and associate them to relevant keys.

```
var func_map = {
  'diensten/consultancy': function () {
    activeOne ();
  },

  'diensten/maatwerk': function () {
    activeTwo ();
    diesntenActive ();
  },

  'diensten/outsourcing': function () {
    activeThree();
    diesntenActive();
  },

  ...

  'cms': function () {
    productenActive();
  }
};

if (name in func_map) func_map[name] ();
else console.log ("No handler found for name = '" + name + "'!");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a perfect situation for a lookup table.  You have a whole bunch of possibilities for the name and your action for each name is just one or more simple function calls.

That means you can use a lookup table.  You put the value for name as the key and an array of function names to call for that name.  One lookup in the table gets you an array of functions to call and you loop through the array to call each one.  This has the advantage that to add more items, you just add a new line to the table without writing any additional lines of code:

```
var lookup = {
    "cms": [productenActive],
    "cebesFrame": [productenActive],
    "firstWatchOnline": [productenActive],
    "fireman": [productenActive],
    "firstwatch": [productenActive],
    "prio": [productenActive],
    "overOns/vacatures": [activeFour, overOnsActive],
    "overOns/partner":  [activeThree, overOnsActive],
    "overOns/cebes": [activeTwo, overOnsActive],
    "overOns": [activeOne, overOnsActive],
    "support/download": [activeThree, supportActive],
    "support/contact": [activeTwo, supportActive],
    "support": [activeOne, supportActive],
    "diensten/implementaties": [activeFive, diesntenActive],
    "diensten/opleidingen": [activeFour, dienstenActive],
    "dienstenout/outsourcing": [activeThree, dienstenActive],
    "diensten/maatwerk": [activeTwo, dienstenActive],
    "diensten/consultancy": [activeOne]
};

var fns = lookup[name];
if (fns) {
    for (var i = 0; i < fns.length; i++) {
        fns[i]();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is silly question, productenActive, activeOne is function, is technique which you explain above support this condition ?, anyway thanks,

Comment: @user1097182 - yes, the table contains function references which the `for` loop executes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt. Its not the best in that its very specialized to your case. However, it does provide a lot of dynamic calling and code reuse.

```
var subPage = {
    'diensten' : ['consultancy', 'maatwerk', 'outsourcing', 'opleidingen', 'implementaties'],
    'support'  : [undefined, 'contact', 'download'],
    'overOns'  : [undefined, 'cebes', 'partner', 'vacatures'],
}
var others = ['fireman', 'prio', 'firstwatch', 'firstwatchOnline', 'cebesFrame', 'cms'];
var active = [activeOne, activeTwo, activeThree, activeFour, activeFive];

var addr = name.split('/');
if (subPage[addr[0]]){
    var index = subPage[addr[0]].indexOf(addr[1]);
    if (index != -1){
        active[index]();
        if (addr[1] !== 'consultancy') // Special case
            this[adder[0]+'Active'](); // Assuming this refers to the scope where diesntenActive() lives
    }
} else if (others.indexOf(addr[0]) != -1){
    productenActive();
}
return false;
```

Anyways, this probably over-complicates things. I would still recommend you either use a switch statement or a lookup table, unless you really really care about reducing your script size. Only in that case might you consider my very specialized approach.

Comment: wow, look complicated, but thanks for your answer, i will consider it.